# Form fields not posting

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with the following fields. For some strange reason phone and message are not being sent in the post request.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="float-left">
            <label for="Name">Full Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
            <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
            <label for="Phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" />
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <label for=comments accesskey=C>Message</label>
            <textarea id="comments" rows="10" cols="10" 
                name="comments"></textarea>
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Send Enquiry</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Post:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
comments    
email   ukkgfpower@hotmail.com
name    Joe Bloggs
phone   
Source
name=Joe Bloggs&email=ukkgfpower%40hotmail.com&phone=&comments=
```

Comment: `phone` and `comments` are there. There are just empty: `&phone=&comments=`. What happens when you populate the fields and post your form?

Comment: I see that phone is being sent just fine, there's no value but it is being sent. You don't have any form element with a name of message, did you mean comments? If so, i see that too.

Comment: yes sorry I meant comment and phone are not being sent, yet they are filled out in the form. Could something else affect them

Comment: @KeithPower Are you checking for these in the script you're submitting to "contact.php"? And are the other fields being passed correctly? As the others have said, I tested the code you have and it works fine.

Comment: Like the others I see no problem and would like to see your PHP code for further analysis

Comment: I am going through the code again. As you point out the form is working, just not on my page. It has to be something else I missed. Thanks for checking it

Comment: Is it possible that you have some kind of javascript running that might be stripping them out? This was my problem. I had a script for making placeHolder work in IE, and it was removing form items.

Comment: Thanks Jake for the response, I had another look at the js files with a fresh mind and the problem was the field names were not set correctly in the js file that handles the ajax submitting. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the field names were not set correctly in the js file that handles the ajax submitting